# Display discounted prices for bulk purchases in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I am looking for a way to display two lines of text right beneath the price on a WooCommerce single product page. The two lines should display the price of the products with a discount of 5% and 10% respectively, something like this:

```
$100 (this is the regular price displayed on the product page)
for 5 pieces: $95
for 10 pieces: $90
```

How can I achieve this nice and clean with as little lines of code as possible?

What I have tried:

```
// Add custom text under product price
function add_custom_text_under_price() {
    global $product;

    // Get the regular price
    $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();

    // Calculate the discounted prices
    $discount_5_percent = $regular_price * 0.95;
    $discount_10_percent = $regular_price * 0.90;

    // Display the custom text
    echo '<p class="discount-text">for 5 pieces: ' . wc_price($discount_5_percent) . '</p>';
    echo '<p class="discount-text">for 10 pieces: ' . wc_price($discount_10_percent) . '</p>';
}

// Hook into the product price display
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'add_custom_text_under_price', 20);
```

However, the price displayed is 0, which makes me think I did not retrieve the regular price in a correct manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following different approach that handle also variable products:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'append_text_under_product_price', 100, 2 );
function append_text_under_product_price( $price_html, $product ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    if ( is_product() && isset($woocommerce_loop['name']) && empty($woocommerce_loop['name']) ) {
        if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
            $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );

            if ( ! empty( $prices['regular_price'] ) ) {
                $min_price = (float) current( $prices['regular_price'] );
                $max_price = (float) end( $prices['regular_price'] );
                if ( $min_price > 0 && $min_price === $max_price ) {
                    $price_html .= '<p class="discount-text">for 5 pieces: ' . wc_price($min_price * 0.95) . '</p>';
                    $price_html .= '<p class="discount-text">for 10 pieces: ' . wc_price($min_price * 0.90) . '</p>';
                } elseif ( $min_price > 0 && $min_price < $max_price ) {
                    $price_html .= '<p class="discount-text">for 5 pieces: ' . wc_price($min_price * 0.95) . ' - ' . wc_price($max_price * 0.95) . '</p>';
                    $price_html .= '<p class="discount-text">for 10 pieces: ' . wc_price($min_price * 0.90) . ' - ' . wc_price($max_price * 0.90) . '</p>';
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $regular_price = (float) $product->get_regular_price();

            if ( $regular_price > 0 ) {
                $price_html .= '<p class="discount-text">for 5 pieces: ' . wc_price($regular_price * 0.95) . '</p>';
                $price_html .= '<p class="discount-text">for 10 pieces: ' . wc_price($regular_price * 0.90) . '</p>';
            }

        }
    }
    return $price_html;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

You could also use the active product price *(instead of the regular price)* like:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'append_text_under_product_price', 100, 2 );
function append_text_under_product_price( $price_html, $product ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    if ( is_product() && isset($woocommerce_loop['name']) && empty($woocommerce_loop['name']) ) {
        if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
            $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );

            if ( ! empty( $prices['price'] ) ) {
                $min_price = (float) current( $prices['price'] );
                $max_price = (float) end( $prices['price'] );
                if ( $min_price > 0 && $min_price === $max_price ) {
                    $price_html .= '<p class="discount-text">for 5 pieces: ' . wc_price($min_price * 0.95) . '</p>';
                    $price_html .= '<p class="discount-text">for 10 pieces: ' . wc_price($min_price * 0.90) . '</p>';
                } elseif ( $min_price > 0 && $min_price < $max_price ) {
                    $price_html .= '<p class="discount-text">for 5 pieces: ' . wc_price($min_price * 0.95) . ' - ' . wc_price($max_price * 0.95) . '</p>';
                    $price_html .= '<p class="discount-text">for 10 pieces: ' . wc_price($min_price * 0.90) . ' - ' . wc_price($max_price * 0.90) . '</p>';
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            $active_price = (float) $product->get_price();

            if ( $active_price > 0 ) {
                $price_html .= '<p class="discount-text">for 5 pieces: ' . wc_price($active_price * 0.95) . '</p>';
                $price_html .= '<p class="discount-text">for 10 pieces: ' . wc_price($active_price * 0.90) . '</p>';
            }

        }
    }
    return $price_html;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.